# while loop messing up

Tags: c++, while-loop

I am trying to write a while loop that exists the while loop when i select actres or movie title. But for some reason its not working its telling me there is an error in the `while (selecton)` line. Anyone have an idea?

```
string selection;

while ( selection )
{
    cin >> selection;

    if ( selection == "actress" )
    {
        cout << "hey" << endl;
        break;
    }
    else if ( selection == "movie title" )
    {
        cout << "bye";
        break;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Please choose a selection";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's supposed to be `while(cin>>selection)`

However it's better to write `while(getline(cin,selection))` so you don't skip white lines.

Comment: I'm not a C++ person, but what does this mean? While selection is greater than 0 length?

Comment: @Ryan while your input of selection is valid.

Comment: Alright i understand what i did, also why isnt "movie title" working when i cin it? It still says make a selection?

Comment: @soniccool, For example, your input of "movie title" would be stored as "movie", with " title\n" left in the input buffer for the next input operation you do.

Comment: Got it i wasnt sure i just figured it out! Thanks Rapptz!!

Comment: @Rapptz I have a question for future reference. Is there a way to make it so if a user types in say a part of the world "actress" that it still accepts it. Say for example `selection == "actress"` But the user types `actres`. is there a way to make it so that partial typing of it will still be acceptable, or do i have to put || and add all the varieties?